# Слой под слоем с картинкой

Tags: css, background

Пытаюсь сделать один слой с картинкой под другим. У первого сверху слоя есть прозрачные окна.
В этих окнах видна картинка нижнего слоя.
Пытялся сделать через background-blend-mode и mix-blend-mode, но не выходит.
Помогите как такое сделать.

```css
.img-back
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.img-back-bg
{
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.img-back-1
{
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 80px;
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
}

.img-back-1:nth-child(odd)
{
    top: -20px;
}

.img-back-1:nth-child(even)
{
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-back">
<div class="img-back-bg">
<div class="img-back-1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="img-back-1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="img-back-1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="img-back-1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="img-back-1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="img-back-1">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="simpleParallax"><img src="https://decorel.by/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/thumb_01644.jpg" alt="IDiNnFjTOZc" width="448" height="336" class="paralax-face"></div></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit]).

Comment: Множественный фон Вы хотите сделать? Т.е. сначала серый фон во всех прямоугольниках, а поверх серого фона в каждом прямоугольнике части птицы?

Comment: Картинка с птицей целая. Я планирую ее двигать при скролле.
Верхний слой с дивами. Но они закрашены. Я думал их через mix-blend-mode сделать прозрачными типа.

Comment: @Androv просто на картинке Вашей это выглядит так, будто фото разрезали на равные части и каждую часть сделали фоном для соответствующего прямоугольника :D

Comment: @Androv приведите, пожалуйста, Ваш код. Так будет проще Вам помочь

Comment: Результат нужен как на картике ниже кода

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону svg так как в нём это решается совсем не сложно

Comment: @Androv, посмотрите в сторону clip-path: polygon. Как у меня в примере https://codepen.io/darinka-poznyak/pen/OJrzLja. Только Вам нужно отрисовать полоски в другом направлении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойство CSS `mask-image`

```css
.mask {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/OLKXkSL.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/OLKXkSL.png);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;    
}
```

```html
<img class="mask" src="https://i.imgur.com/vPtZulv.png" />
```

**UPD**: С эффектом паралакса при скроллинге страницы.

```js
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let parallax = document.querySelector('.parallax');
    let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    parallax.style.backgroundPositionY = scrollPosition * 0.7 + 'px';
  });
```

```css
  .parallax {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/vPtZulv.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .mask {
    -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/OLKXkSL.png);
    mask-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/OLKXkSL.png);
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mask parallax"></div>
```

Comment: Немного не то. У меня фоновая картинка паралаксом будет двигаться. А окружности должны оставаться на месте.

Comment: @Androv а эффект паралакса при каком действии должен проявляться?

Comment: да паралакс для картинки с птицей будет. она двигается при скролле.

Comment: @Androv обновил ответ

Comment: Отлично. То что надо. Немного доработать анимацию и готово. Она у меня горизонтальная.

Comment: @Androv Если вам помог мой ответ, отметьте серую галочку снизу голосов, это пометит ответ как верный.